# Possible proof that $1 = 2$? No it can't be! So why do I keep concluding to that?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

So my teacher gives me a problem to work with:

> > Let $n = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{\cdots}}}} \ $ then how must you solve for $n$?
> >
> > Solution:
> >
> > $$n = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{\cdots}}}} \Rightarrow n = \sqrt{1 + n} \Rightarrow n^2 - 1 = n \Rightarrow n^2 - n - 1 = 0$$ $$\therefore n = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$ However, $n > 0$ $$\therefore n = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = 1.6180339887\ldots = φ \neq \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$$ Now we can substitute $n = φ$ into the following equation to double-check: $$\begin{align} n^2 - 1 &= n \Rightarrow φ^2 - 1 = φ \Rightarrow \bigg(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^2 - 1 = \frac{(1 + \sqrt{5})^2}{2^2} - 1 = \frac{6 + 2\sqrt{5}}{4} - 1 \\ &= \frac{6 + 2\sqrt{5}}{4} - \frac{4}{4} = \frac{2 + 2\sqrt{5}}{4} = \frac{2}{2}\times \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = 1\times \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = \boxed{\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}} \quad \color{green}{\checkmark} \end{align}$$

My teacher said, "Very good... Now try this problem."

> > Let $n = \frac{2}{3 - \frac{2}{3 - \frac{2}{3 - \frac{2}{\cdots}}}} \ $ then how do you solve for $n$?

No matter *what* I do, I always get that $n = 1 = 2 \Rightarrow \boxed{1 = 2}$ !!! I used the same method as I did for the previous question, so why isn't it working? And of course my teacher just said in response, "work on it as part of your homework". Could somebody please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well it can't equal $(1 - \sqrt{5})/2$ can it? I see what you mean though. For instance, take $n < -1$ but I guess the teacher knew what I meant, however for the purposes of your understanding and for other users I will change it

Comment: Yes it can't but the line is still wrong.

Comment: How do you know that $n$ exists?

Comment: What do you mean by 
$n=\frac2{3-\frac2{3-}}?$
You have to be more careful. Define $n=\lim_{k\to+\infty}x_k$ where
$x_k=\frac2{3-x_{k-1}}.$
This difference equation has two fixed points, namely $x=1$ and $x=2$, but only $x=1$ is stable. Hence, if you define $n$ as I suggested, only the stable fixed point corresponds to a valid solution.

Comment: I just let $n = \dfrac{2}{3 - n}$ and realised that $n = 1 = 2$. And @mrf, that is a good point if you think about it, I guess

Comment: @user477343 Pattern matching doesn't always work.

Comment: @A---B if so, are there any other techniques I could use apart from what $@GerhardS. has mentioned?

Comment: "I just let $n=\frac2{3−n}$ and realised that $n=1=2$" This is meaningless. If $n=\frac2{3−n}$ then $n=1$ **OR** $n=2$. Please explain "and realised that $n=1=2$".

Comment: @Did Ooooohhhh I did not think of it like that! I mean, at first I did, but I assumed there was only one solution which ties down to what $@mrf said earlier... ha

Comment: You get $n=1$ or $n=2$ - two possible solutions - how do you discriminate between them as you did with the two solutions in the first example? Or can you?

Comment: @MarkBennet it all came down to my assumption that there existed only one solution. I mean, in the previous example, $n = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \neq \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and somehow through that level of thinking, I just randomly subconsciously thought that there existed only *one* solution for $n$ in the following example....look, I don't know to be honest, but thank you all for the pick up :)

Comment: @mrf $n$ must exist, it is a continued fraction, hence a representation of a real number. What I struggle with is the fact that it is an infinite continued fraction, hence it should represent an irrational number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

Comment: @pepa.dvorak Well there is *this* funny equation which I have seen all over the place: $$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + \cdots + \infty = -\frac{1}{12}$$ and that is rational... and yes it looks *completely* out of the blue ordinary but if you really stop to smell the roses, *just* maybe you can find an explanation. There are heaps of proofs and justifications :)

Comment: @pepa.dvorak The uniqueness of the value of a continued fraction holds when every term is positive. I see no reason why it should also hold when, as here, infinitely many of these terms are negative.

Comment: @user477343 No, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n$ is not equal $-\frac1{12}$. But believe me, it would be better to avoid opening this other can of worms now and to stick to your original question...

Comment: @Did hah true on the first note because you have in the overall denominator $3 + -\frac{2}{\cdots}$. And on the second note, why have I seen that it does equal this? I did not mean to open a can of worms as you put it, so sorry about that

Comment: Here are some links to show you what I mean if you are curious about the $-1/12$ thing: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jcKRGpMiVTw and  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYw and here are two videos from the same channel with two different proofs: $(1)$ https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww and $(2)$ https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=E-d9mgo8FGk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use the same method as in your first example, (substituting n back into your infinite continuous fraction)

$$ 3-n=\frac{2}{n}$$
You can simplify to obtain: $ 3n-n^2=2 $, which works for any n
, as $n \neq 0$.
By factorising, you get the solutions $n = 1, $ OR $2$, not $1=2$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I find this answer the best because it is $100$% understandable and easy to apply from. Thank you, and congratulations! $$(+1) \ \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Answer (score 5):

It is because $2\over3-{2\over3-{2\over...}}$ do not have a single meaning.

It can mean the limit of

$$2, {2\over3-2}, {2\over3-{2\over3-2}}, ...$$

or the limit of

$${2\over3}, {2\over3-{2\over3}}, {2\over3-{2\over3-{2\over3}}}, ...$$

The first series converges to 2, and the second one converges to 1.

Comment: Yes I did some research as to where to find this problem and I found it on a *Mathologer* Video on YouTube who used this method, however, although I am fond of limits, I much prefer factorising as @AmeenaH put it. $(+1)$ though :) (in 37 minutes because I reached my limit of voting)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
  p_{n} &= 2q_{n-1} \\
  q_{n} &= 3q_{n-1}-p_{n-1} \\
  \frac{p_n}{q_n} &= \frac{2}{3-\dfrac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}}\\
  p_{n} &= 2^{n}(2q_{0}-p_{0})+2(p_{0}-q_{0}) \\
  q_{n} &= 2^{n}(2q_{0}-p_{0})+(p_{0}-q_{0}) \\
\end{align}

- **Case I**: $p_{0}=2q_{0} \ne 0$

$$\frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}=2$$

- **Case II**: $p_{0} \ne 2q_{0}$ and $q_{n} \ne 0$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}=1$$

Comment: I am sorry but this looks a little bit far from my skill level, or at least, I don't write the equations *this* way...however, it does look pretty so $(+1)$ :)